# How to add wp visual editor in a custom widget?

Tags: plugins, widgets, visual-editor, wysiwyg

I am developing a widget plugin and want to add a textarea with WYSIWYG editor in widget settings.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked [TinyMCE in Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE) and some relative searches on google?

Answer (score 1):

Embedding WYSIWYG Editor in Custom widget needs the declaration of the fields under a form function, this will create a WYSIWYG Editor in your widget.
You can define your parameter, what all features you want to show.

```
public function form( $instance ) {

    $rand    = rand( 0, 999 );
    $ed_id   = $this->get_field_id( 'wp_editor_' . $rand );
    $ed_name = $this->get_field_name( 'wp_editor_' . $rand );
    $content   = 'Hello World!';
    $editor_id = $ed_id;
    $settings = array('media_buttons' => true,'textarea_rows' => 4,'textarea_name' => $ed_name,'teeny' => true,);
    wp_editor( $content, $editor_id, $settings );
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try plugins like this:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-editor-widget/screenshots/
https://wordpress.org/plugins/black-studio-tinymce-widget/screenshots/

This plugins works all widgets

Comment: You did not understand my words. I meant to say, how can I implement Visual Editor in a custom widget?

Comment: Recommendations and links aren't answers, answers need to be self contained